# DMA and the possible movability of kernel mode memory allocations

Tags: linux-kernel, dma

Of course in general the physical memory behind user mode allocations (e. g. pointers returned by malloc()) might very well move to some different physical address at the discretion of the kernel (for example if the memory is swapped to disk and is later recalled to some other segment of physical memory).  However the user mode code will be unaffected as on those occasions the kernel will update the page tables to point to the new location with no change to the virtual address being used by the user.

If this (perhaps discontiguous) physical memory is to be the target of some DMA then there are the user mode mlock() and munlock() calls to prevent this this memory from being paged out and you can call get_user_pages() etc. to get the physical addresses to feed to the DMA hardware and so on.  That’s all well and good- but that’s not my case.

Rather I have done some kernel mode allocations (using __get_free_pages()) to obtain physically contiguous memory as our PCIe card-based DMA engine does not support scatter-gather.  All of this has been working fine for some time- until I encountered a motherboard on which I see hard crashes.

I have thus far not worried that the kernel might at any time just move the physical memory locations for these ranges (resulting in my DMA card writing data to the wrong locations).

But with the new crashes on this motherboard now have me questioning that assumption.

Can that kernel memory allocated with __get_free_pages() too be moved by the kernel at any time to a different physical address range?

And if so is there any kernel facility to prevent these moves?

Comment: How is this possible? You have allocated concrete pages, they are related to concrete region of physical RAM. And this pages continuous to be this pages.

Comment: The crashes have a different cause.